# Inventory Google Sheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Can someone help me with this situation, I'm receiving a Deliveries of Bulk Materials, and I'm trying to make a one sheet inventory, where the deliveries, pullout, and summary are all in one place (Sheet).

This is so far where I come up.

This is how it works, basically, it's based on dates where you received the materials, my problem here is when I received 2 bulk materials in one day, it's gonna less on the 1st material because it has the same date as the second material.

[image]

This is the only formula I'm using

```
=if(A5="","",SUMIFS(I:I,F:F,A:A)-SUMIFS(N:N,K:K,A:A))
```

Comment: What are we supposed to get ?. 5 instead of 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Sumifs is not enough as you compare only dates and if you have also inventory codes - to keep stock you should keep track not only for dates but also for names and codes.

What I propose is a filter formula (but it can be solved also using query).

First you filter out all the same products from each day (I combine together 3 columns) in "remaining" column and compare against the same 3 columns in Divert table. Then I sum the values.

Then I do the same filter for Pullout values (I filter all the pullouts from a day for a certain product).

Together it makes:

```
    =sum(filter($I$10:$I,$F$10:$F&$G$10:$G&$H$10:$H=A10&B10&C10))
-sum(filter($N$10:$N,$K$10:$K&$L$10:$L&$M$10:$M=A10&B10&C10))
```

[image]

My solution is here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifZshp2qnORN6w7R7ztb-7a2rIW7EtOuhYnr6utFn48/edit?usp=sharing

You can also automate your 'remaining' table pulling out all the unique rows from divert table.

[image]

This will erase all the duplicates which you don't need as you have sums.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
=QUERY({{F3:H;K3:M},{I3:I;INDEX(N3:N*-1)}}, 
            "select Col1, Col2, Col3, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null
             group by Col1, Col2, Col3 label sum(Col4) '' ",0)
```

[image]

By using `INDEX(N3:N*-1)` we actually subtract column `N`